# Web Notifications API - Is there a way to close all displayed notifications

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, notifications

With Web Notifications API, the app can end up displaying 5+ notifications. The notifications do not automatically close. Is there a method available that will close all open desktop notifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call the `.cancel()` handler on your notification variable